# jenkins hangs after Augmented all extensions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

**jenkins hangs at startup.**

**tail -10f /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log**

```
    Jul 07, 2017 5:12:16 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
    INFO: Started initialization
    Jul 07, 2017 5:12:16 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
    INFO: Listed all plugins
    Jul 07, 2017 5:12:18 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
    INFO: Prepared all plugins
    Jul 07, 2017 5:12:18 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
    INFO: Started all plugins
    Jul 07, 2017 5:12:18 PM jenkins.InitReactorRunner$1 onAttained
    INFO: Augmented all extensions
```

**java -version**

```
java version "1.8.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_45-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.45-b02, mixed mode)
```

**jenkins version** ==> 2.60

**Error in browser:**

```
Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work...

Your browser will reload automatically when Jenkins is ready
```

Tried:

```
1) restart jenkins and server
2) Changing the java version
3) Removed all jobs, etc
```

Noting works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: After `INFO: Augmented all extensions`, there should be something like `INFO: Loaded all jobs`. You could try whether Jenkins starts up with an empty `JENKINS_HOME` (i.e., pointing to an empty directory). You could clone [Jenkins](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins), build it, and then try to find out where startup hangs. There is a `stable-2.60` branch.

Comment: I have Tried doing with Empty "JENKINS_HOME". I have tried to clear the cache  /var/cache/jenkins . Now i have strange issue "WARNING: badMessage: 413 for HttpChannelOverHttp@344ab40e{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=/}"

Comment: Looks like 413 refers to the HTTP status code _Request entity too large_. You can check HTTP traffic using the browsers dev tooling. However I'm not sure whether to follow this lead or not. This just looks strange.

Comment: Hmm. I seem to have the same problem starting today. After "INFO: Augmented all extensions" multiple 
"skipping symbolic link .* -- too many levels of symbolic links" are reported. that ends then . . . . jenkins never comes up .  .the jstack threadDump doesn't look useful but I will post mine below.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [similar issue filled here JENKINS-36931](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36931)

> To find out what Jenkins is doing during startup, especially when appearing to hang, follow these instructions:

"[Obtaining a thread dump](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Obtaining+a+thread+dump)"

With that Thread dump, you can at least know where Jenkins is stopping and what it was doing.

Comment: I found 'lsof -p pid' helped, also /var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log was giving me a hint. fstrigger plugin behaviour was my problem. disabling latest changed plugins or jobs helped to track down my problem.

Comment: @vonc thanks. In the past we found different plugin updates caused jenkins to not work. Staying up to date with jenkins and plugins is good but on occasion the updates caused an issue. This time it was a job change which added plugin config which was our problem. Anyway I think the first place to look is the jenkins.log. The jenkins thread dump I'm not sure was it working properly for me. I ran it several times and output was similar. It didn't help me to trace the problem back to the naughty plugin. :-7

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have the same problem starting today. After "INFO: Augmented all extensions" multiple "skipping symbolic link .* -- too many levels of symbolic links" are reported. that ends then . . . . jenkins never comes up, "Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work.."

***UPDATE: WORKAROUND: Disable fstrigger plugin.***

```
$ touch /var/lib/jenkins/plugins/fstrigger.jpi.disabled
$ systemctl restart jenkins
```

I tried restoring older jenkins config from backups but that didn't work. I looked at recent job changes and found that removing some new jobs allowed jenkins to start. When jenkins was failing to start lsof -p pid showed that it was slowly browsing through a fileststem that was consigured for fstrigger to watch. Disabling fstrigger allowed jenkins to start with the new jobs config.

So. I think MY problem is bug in fstrigger on startup.
I think bug is with fstrigger monitoring a directory with a large structure underneath (possibly recursive symlinks linking internal to the dir structure  (messages in log) are related).

The jstack threadDump doesn't look useful ? To me.

but here is what I see anyway: . .

```
$ jstack 5670
5670: Unable to open socket file: target process not responding or HotSpot VM not loaded
The -F option can be used when the target process is not responding
$ jstack -F 5670
Attaching to process ID 5670, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.144-b01
Deadlock Detection:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deduce type of thread from address 0x00007fe12c041800 (expected type JavaThread, CompilerThread, ServiceThread, JvmtiAgentThread, or SurrogateLockerThread)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:169)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.first(Threads.java:153)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.createThreadTable(DeadlockDetector.java:149)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:56)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.DeadlockDetector.print(DeadlockDetector.java:39)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:62)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:66)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.types.WrongTypeException: No suitable match for type of address 0x00007fe12c041800
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.InstanceConstructor.newWrongTypeException(InstanceConstructor.java:62)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VirtualConstructor.instantiateWrapperFor(VirtualConstructor.java:80)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:165)
        ... 17 more
Can't print deadlocks:Unable to deduce type of thread from address 0x00007fe12c041800 (expected type JavaThread, CompilerThread, ServiceThread, JvmtiAgentThread, or SurrogateLockerThread)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
        at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to deduce type of thread from address 0x00007fe12c041800 (expected type JavaThread, CompilerThread, ServiceThread, JvmtiAgentThread, or SurrogateLockerThread)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:169)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.first(Threads.java:153)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:75)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.StackTrace.run(StackTrace.java:45)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.run(JStack.java:66)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: sun.jvm.hotspot.types.WrongTypeException: No suitable match for type of address 0x00007fe12c041800
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.InstanceConstructor.newWrongTypeException(InstanceConstructor.java:62)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VirtualConstructor.instantiateWrapperFor(VirtualConstructor.java:80)
        at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.Threads.createJavaThreadWrapper(Threads.java:165)
        ... 14 more
```

strace/gdb ?

```
$ ps -elf |grep 5670
```

0 S jenkins   5670     1 93  80   0 - 2791171 futex_ 11:19 ?      00:20:50 /etc/alternatives/java -Dcom.sun.akuma.Daemon=daemonized -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -DJENKINS_HOME=/var/lib/jenkins -jar /usr/lib/jenkins/jenkins.war --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --daemon --httpPort=8086 --debug=5 --handlerCountMax=100 --handlerCountMaxIdle=20
0 S root      6883  5207  0  80   0 - 28160 pipe_w 11:41 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto 5670

```
$ strace -p 5670
Process 5670 attached
futex(0x7fe2a78a59d0, FUTEX_WAIT, 5672, NULL



$ gdb -q -p 5670 /etc/alternatives/java 
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Attaching to program: /etc/alternatives/java, process 5670

warning: Could not load shared library symbols for /tmp/jna--1712433994/jna4154053066660760454.tmp.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
Reading symbols from /lib64/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New LWP 6866]
[New LWP 5781]
[New LWP 5780]
[New LWP 5779]
[New LWP 5778]
[New LWP 5777]
[New LWP 5776]
[New LWP 5775]
[New LWP 5774]
[New LWP 5773]
[New LWP 5772]
[New LWP 5771]
[New LWP 5770]
[New LWP 5769]
[New LWP 5768]
[New LWP 5767]
[New LWP 5766]
[New LWP 5765]
[New LWP 5764]
[New LWP 5763]
[New LWP 5762]
[New LWP 5761]
[New LWP 5760]
[New LWP 5759]
[New LWP 5757]
[New LWP 5756]
[New LWP 5755]
[New LWP 5754]
[New LWP 5753]
[New LWP 5752]
[New LWP 5751]
[New LWP 5750]
[New LWP 5749]
[New LWP 5748]
[New LWP 5747]
[New LWP 5746]
[New LWP 5745]
[New LWP 5744]
[New LWP 5743]
[New LWP 5742]
[New LWP 5741]
[New LWP 5740]
[New LWP 5739]
[New LWP 5738]
[New LWP 5737]
[New LWP 5736]
[New LWP 5735]
[New LWP 5734]
[New LWP 5733]
[New LWP 5732]
[New LWP 5731]
[New LWP 5730]
[New LWP 5729]
[New LWP 5728]
[New LWP 5727]
[New LWP 5726]
[New LWP 5725]
[New LWP 5724]
[New LWP 5723]
[New LWP 5722]
[New LWP 5721]
[New LWP 5720]
[New LWP 5719]
[New LWP 5718]
[New LWP 5717]
[New LWP 5716]
[New LWP 5715]
[New LWP 5714]
[New LWP 5713]
[New LWP 5712]
[New LWP 5708]
[New LWP 5707]
[New LWP 5706]
[New LWP 5705]
[New LWP 5704]
[New LWP 5703]
[New LWP 5702]
[New LWP 5701]
[New LWP 5700]
[New LWP 5699]
[New LWP 5698]
[New LWP 5697]
[New LWP 5696]
[New LWP 5695]
[New LWP 5694]
[New LWP 5689]
[New LWP 5688]
[New LWP 5687]
[New LWP 5685]
[New LWP 5684]
[New LWP 5683]
[New LWP 5682]
[New LWP 5681]
[New LWP 5680]
[New LWP 5679]
[New LWP 5678]
[New LWP 5677]
[New LWP 5676]
[New LWP 5675]
[New LWP 5674]
[New LWP 5673]
[New LWP 5672]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib64/libz.so.1...Reading symbols from /lib64/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(no debugging symbols found)...done.
.
.
Loaded symbols for /lib64/libresolv.so.2
0x00007fe2a7484ef7 in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install freetype-2.4.11-9.el7.x86_64 glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.3-9.el7.x86_64 nspr-4.13.1-1.0.el7_3.x86_64 nss-3.28.4-12.el7_4.x86_64 nss-softokn-freebl-3.28.3-8.el7_4.x86_64 nss-util-3.28.4-3.el7.x86_64 zlib-1.2.7-13.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fe2a7484ef7 in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007fe2a705f3e5 in ContinueInNewThread0 () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
#2  0x00007fe2a705bb72 in ContinueInNewThread () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
#3  0x00007fe2a705c7f2 in JLI_Launch () from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/../lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so
#4  0x000000000040068c in main ()
(gdb) info threads
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  103  Thread 0x7fe2a78a5700 (LWP 5672) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  102  Thread 0x7fe2a4158700 (LWP 5673) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  101  Thread 0x7fe290b31700 (LWP 5674) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  100  Thread 0x7fe290a30700 (LWP 5675) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  99   Thread 0x7fe29092f700 (LWP 5676) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  98   Thread 0x7fe29082e700 (LWP 5677) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  97   Thread 0x7fe29072d700 (LWP 5678) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  96   Thread 0x7fe29062c700 (LWP 5679) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  95   Thread 0x7fe29052b700 (LWP 5680) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  94   Thread 0x7fe29042a700 (LWP 5681) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  93   Thread 0x7fe290329700 (LWP 5682) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  92   Thread 0x7fe290228700 (LWP 5683) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  91   Thread 0x7fe290127700 (LWP 5684) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  90   Thread 0x7fe290026700 (LWP 5685) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  89   Thread 0x7fe28c5e9700 (LWP 5687) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  88   Thread 0x7fe28c4e8700 (LWP 5688) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  87   Thread 0x7fe28c3e7700 (LWP 5689) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  86   Thread 0x7fe28c2e6700 (LWP 5694) "java" 0x00007fe2a7489790 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  85   Thread 0x7fe28c1e5700 (LWP 5695) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  84   Thread 0x7fe25332f700 (LWP 5696) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  83   Thread 0x7fe25322e700 (LWP 5697) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  82   Thread 0x7fe25312d700 (LWP 5698) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  81   Thread 0x7fe25302c700 (LWP 5699) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  80   Thread 0x7fe252f2b700 (LWP 5700) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  79   Thread 0x7fe252e2a700 (LWP 5701) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  78   Thread 0x7fe252d29700 (LWP 5702) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  77   Thread 0x7fe252c28700 (LWP 5703) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  76   Thread 0x7fe252b27700 (LWP 5704) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  75   Thread 0x7fe252a26700 (LWP 5705) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  74   Thread 0x7fe252925700 (LWP 5706) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  73   Thread 0x7fe252824700 (LWP 5707) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  72   Thread 0x7fe252723700 (LWP 5708) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  71   Thread 0x7fe252100700 (LWP 5712) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  70   Thread 0x7fe23d3d5700 (LWP 5713) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  69   Thread 0x7fe23c1ea700 (LWP 5714) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  68   Thread 0x7fe1f7de5700 (LWP 5715) "java" 0x00007fe2a6b88863 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  67   Thread 0x7fe1f7ce4700 (LWP 5716) "java" 0x00007fe2a6b88863 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  66   Thread 0x7fe1f7be3700 (LWP 5717) "java" 0x00007fe2a6b88863 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  65   Thread 0x7fe1f7ae2700 (LWP 5718) "java" 0x00007fe2a6b88863 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  64   Thread 0x7fe1f79e1700 (LWP 5719) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  63   Thread 0x7fe1f78e0700 (LWP 5720) "java" 0x00007fe2a748a4ad in accept () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  62   Thread 0x7fe1f77df700 (LWP 5721) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  61   Thread 0x7fe1f74de700 (LWP 5722) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  60   Thread 0x7fe1f73dd700 (LWP 5723) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  59   Thread 0x7fe1f72dc700 (LWP 5724) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  58   Thread 0x7fe1f71db700 (LWP 5725) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
  57   Thread 0x7fe1f70da700 (LWP 5726) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  56   Thread 0x7fe1f6fd9700 (LWP 5727) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  55   Thread 0x7fe1f6ed8700 (LWP 5728) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  54   Thread 0x7fe1f6dd7700 (LWP 5729) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  53   Thread 0x7fe1f6cd6700 (LWP 5730) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  52   Thread 0x7fe1f6bd5700 (LWP 5731) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  51   Thread 0x7fe1f6ad4700 (LWP 5732) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  50   Thread 0x7fe1f69d3700 (LWP 5733) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  49   Thread 0x7fe1f68d2700 (LWP 5734) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  48   Thread 0x7fe1f67d1700 (LWP 5735) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  47   Thread 0x7fe1f66d0700 (LWP 5736) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  46   Thread 0x7fe1f63cf700 (LWP 5737) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  45   Thread 0x7fe1f62ce700 (LWP 5738) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  44   Thread 0x7fe1f61cd700 (LWP 5739) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  43   Thread 0x7fe1f60cc700 (LWP 5740) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  42   Thread 0x7fe1f5fcb700 (LWP 5741) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  41   Thread 0x7fe252622700 (LWP 5742) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  40   Thread 0x7fe1f5eca700 (LWP 5743) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  39   Thread 0x7fe1f5dc9700 (LWP 5744) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  38   Thread 0x7fe1f5cc8700 (LWP 5745) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  37   Thread 0x7fe1f5bc7700 (LWP 5746) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  36   Thread 0x7fe1f5ac6700 (LWP 5747) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  35   Thread 0x7fe1f59c5700 (LWP 5748) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  34   Thread 0x7fe1f58c4700 (LWP 5749) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  33   Thread 0x7fe1f57c3700 (LWP 5750) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  32   Thread 0x7fe1f56c2700 (LWP 5751) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  31   Thread 0x7fe1f55c1700 (LWP 5752) "java" 0x00007fe2a748a22d in read () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  30   Thread 0x7fe1f54c0700 (LWP 5753) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  29   Thread 0x7fe1f53bf700 (LWP 5754) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  28   Thread 0x7fe1f52be700 (LWP 5755) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  27   Thread 0x7fe1f51bd700 (LWP 5756) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  26   Thread 0x7fe1f50bc700 (LWP 5757) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  25   Thread 0x7fe1f4dbb700 (LWP 5759) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  24   Thread 0x7fe1f4cba700 (LWP 5760) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  23   Thread 0x7fe1f4bb9700 (LWP 5761) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  22   Thread 0x7fe1f4476700 (LWP 5762) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  21   Thread 0x7fe1f416c700 (LWP 5763) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  20   Thread 0x7fe12bfff700 (LWP 5764) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  19   Thread 0x7fe12befe700 (LWP 5765) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  18   Thread 0x7fe12bdfd700 (LWP 5766) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  17   Thread 0x7fe12bc6a700 (LWP 5767) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  16   Thread 0x7fe12b969700 (LWP 5768) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  15   Thread 0x7fe12b868700 (LWP 5769) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  14   Thread 0x7fe12af2c700 (LWP 5770) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  13   Thread 0x7fe12ae2b700 (LWP 5771) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  12   Thread 0x7fe12ad2a700 (LWP 5772) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  11   Thread 0x7fe12aa29700 (LWP 5773) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
  10   Thread 0x7fe12a128700 (LWP 5774) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  9    Thread 0x7fe129a27700 (LWP 5775) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  8    Thread 0x7fe129926700 (LWP 5776) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  7    Thread 0x7fe129825700 (LWP 5777) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  6    Thread 0x7fe129724700 (LWP 5778) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  5    Thread 0x7fe129623700 (LWP 5779) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  4    Thread 0x7fe129522700 (LWP 5780) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  3    Thread 0x7fe129021700 (LWP 5781) "java" 0x00007fe2a74876d5 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
  2    Thread 0x7fe128b20700 (LWP 6866) "java" 0x00007fe2a7487a82 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
* 1    Thread 0x7fe2a78a6740 (LWP 5670) "java" 0x00007fe2a7484ef7 in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) 
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fe252d29700 (LWP 5702)]
0x00007fe2a633d7e0 in Monitor::wait(bool, long, bool) ()
   from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fe1f7de5700 (LWP 5715)]
0x00007fe29159dd13 in ?? ()
(gdb) quit
A debugging session is active.

        Inferior 1 [process 5670] will be detached.

Quit anyway? (y or n) y
Detaching from program: /etc/alternatives/java, process 5670
$ ls -alstr /etc/alternatives/java 
4 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 73 Oct 12 14:21 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.144-0.b01.el7_4.x86_64/jre/bin/java
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, clearing the directories (only the directories, not the hpi/jpi files) under home/plugins directory helps. Make sure the server is not running before deleting the directories.